# How to target object for v-for

Tags: vuejs2, v-for

```
created() {
  const currentActivity = this.$store.getters.currentActivity
  const activity = currentActivity.activity
}
```

The object I want to loop through its properties, is **activity**.
Its content displays fine in the console.
Inside the template I have:

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="value in activity" :key="value.id">
    {{ value.activity.activityName }}
    {{ value.related_Activity }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Inside data():

```
return {
  activity: activity
}
```

But the console says: `"activity is not defined"`
I tried `this.activity`, no errors in console but it doesn't display anything on the page.
So, **how to refer the the activity object**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very close to @RenatoManalili answer.

`this.currentActivity = currentActivity` did the job.

Also, I update the template code as so:

````
<ul v-for="value in currentActivity" :key="value.id">
  <li>{{ value.activity.activityName }}</li>
  <li>{{ value.related_activity }}</li>
</ul>
``` because it wasn't properly displaying the list.
Thank you.
````

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `const activity = currentActivity.activity`
change it to `this.activity = currentActivity.activity` and then in your data `return { activity: [] }`

Comment: Thanks for the cue, that was close!